# How to compare two int variables in a if cycle

Tags: java, android, if-statement, int, equals

I have a little problem with my codes. I want to `compare 2 int variables` in a if cycle. I know that there are some difference between `logical operator == and method .equals();`

My code is:

portion of the code where is the problem:

The problem is`result02==var`. I don't receive any error from Eclipse logcat.

I try to use`result02.equals(var)` but don't run.

```
else{
         if (conferma_text.getText().toString().equals(password_text.getText().toString())){
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbLogin.getWritableDatabase();
            int result02 = verifyL.verify(db, login_text.getText().toString(), password_text.getText().toString());
            int var =-1;
            if(result02==var){
```

check my complete codes:

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class CreateAccountActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginDataBase dbLogin;
    VerifyLogin verifyL = new VerifyLogin();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbLogin = new LoginDataBase(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.createaccount);
        Button button_crea02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Create02);
        button_crea02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                executeCreate();
            }
        });
    }

    //Per prima cosa si verifica che tutte le EdiText siano compilate, in caso negativo
    //una notifica toast avvisa l'utente dell'errore.
    private void executeCreate(){
       EditText login_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName02);
       EditText password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password02);
       EditText conferma_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Conferma);
       EmptyField emptyf = new EmptyField();
       String result=emptyf.CreateEmpty(login_text, password_text, conferma_text);
       if (result.equals("Empty")){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Fornire i dati richiesti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
       }
       //Se le EditText sono compilate si verifica che le credenziali di accesso non
       //siano già associate ad un altro utente, in tal caso si avvisa l'utente con una
       //notifica toast. Se le credenziali sono corrette si procede al loro inserimento
       //nel DB.
       else{
         if (conferma_text.getText().toString().equals(password_text.getText().toString())){
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbLogin.getWritableDatabase();
            int result02 = verifyL.verify(db, login_text.getText().toString(), password_text.getText().toString());
            int var =-1;
            if(result02==var){

                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                 values.put("USERNAME",login_text.getText().toString());
                 values.put("PASSWORD",password_text.getText().toString());      
                 long id = db.insert("T_LOGIN", null, values);
                 if (id != -1){
                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Record creato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     toast.show();
                 }
             }
            else{
                //Se username e password esistono già viene lanciata un AlertDialog. Premendo Ok
                //si puliscono le EditText
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Attenzione");
                builder.setMessage("Username e Password invalidi");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        EditText login_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName02);
                        EditText password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password02);
                        EditText conferma_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Conferma);
                        login_text.setText("");
                        password_text.setText("");
                        conferma_text.setText("");
                        dialog.cancel();                        
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            }
         }
         //Se la password inserita e quella di conferma non corrispondono si avvisa l'utente
         else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Le password non corrispondono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `equals()` is for objects, `==` for raw data types (int, float, char, ...).

Comment: so where is the problem in my script? My if cycle don't run. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no, no Error. So my code look like correct? Maybe the problem is in my if logic and not in the code?

Comment: What is the value of `result02`?

Comment: I expect an int variable -1.

Comment: I guess that that was what you expected, but what was the value it contained? You may be getting another value.

Comment: ok Ok, How I can control my variable value??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP lacks a minimal understanding of the basic debugging process. Please refer to the help section and http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

For primitives like - int, boolean, long etc - you should use `==`.

Primitives are not object so you can not call a method on them.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether actually it is getting inside

```
 if (conferma_text.getText().toString().equals(password_text.getText().toString())){

//Use log here to check 

}
```

Comment: what?? I don't understund.

Comment: May be  if (conferma_text.getText().toString().equals(password_text.getText().toString())) returing false and you are not getting into this condition

Comment: Oh ok. I try this condition and it run well. The problem is the second if.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives do not use the .equals(). Use your == on them. If you wish to use the .equals() method they must be put into the wrapper class (i.e Integer). Then you can use the .equals().